# How do I save $.getJSON results as php variable?

Tags: php, json, getjson

I want to save what `$("#price").text(data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);` displays in html as a php variable or array. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var symbol = ['DJI', 'NDAQ'];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
                var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol[i] + "')");
                $.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env")
                    .done(function (data) {
                    $("#price").text(data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
                    js_price.push(data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
                    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = js_price;

                })
                    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                        $("#result").text('Request failed: ' + err);
                });

    }
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="price"></div>
```

How do I save the JSON content of $("#id") as a php variable?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You wanted to fetch a data via Ajax then save it as a php variable so that you can use it as PHP on the same page ?

Comment: Yes. But I do not know how to convert the getJSON statement to an Ajax statement.

Comment: You can't do that. Javascript is Client Side. PHP is server side. Even if you try to get the variable via Ajax, the moment it returns back your PHP page is already done parsing. You can use Ajax, but you can't use the results as a PHP Variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
$("#price").JSON.parse(data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
```

and then the **id="price"** will show your result in JSON format.

Comment: But that is still in JSON format. How would I save the contents of id="price" as a php variable?

Comment: you have two methods to do this via = .ajax() AND by creating form with submit button to send the variable in PHP page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer the requested data to PHP you need to do an ajax request to your webserver transfering the required data.

Comment: How would I convert the getJSON request to an ajax request?